# Can't use provisioned space on thin virtual disk

Tags: linux, rhel, virtual-machine, lvm, disk-usage

I have this issue with my virtualized RHEL 7.1.

I created this VM with thin-provisioned disk. I thought that I know how it should work - provisioned space would be available to the VM, but as long as it is not really used, it won't be blocked on storage.

But when I'm working with VM, I don't really have the space available. I need more space on my /root dir. There's some output from terminal:

```
[root@rheldemo ~]# df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel_rheldemo-root  2.9G  1.1G  1.8G  37% /
devtmpfs                        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           1.9G  148K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           1.9G   17M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel_rheldemo-usr   9.8G  3.4G  5.9G  37% /usr
/dev/mapper/rhel_rheldemo-var   6.8G  3.6G  2.9G  55% /var
/dev/sda1                       240M  102M  122M  46% /boot
/dev/mapper/rhel_rheldemo-tmp   2.0G   16M  1.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/rhel_rheldemo-home   56G   23G   31G  42% /home

[root@rheldemo ~]# lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
LV Name                pool00
VG Name                rhel_rheldemo
LV UUID                xL5eEu-fNZG-ds3B-GcOk-rWHK-YMaT-367Tk8
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-03-07 13:11:08 +0100
LV Pool metadata       pool00_tmeta
LV Pool data           pool00_tdata
LV Status              available
# open                 6
LV Size                78.79 GiB
Allocated pool data    43.83%
Allocated metadata     19.98%
Current LE             20169
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     8192
Block device           253:2

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/rhel_rheldemo/root
LV Name                root
VG Name                rhel_rheldemo
LV UUID                p0F2hQ-qgJ7-77UM-pdzR-yMzV-SboH-p3rhDp
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-03-07 13:11:08 +0100
LV Pool name           pool00
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                3.00 GiB
Mapped size            35.95%
Current LE             768
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     8192
Block device           253:3
...

[root@rheldemo ~]# lvs
LV     VG            Attr       LSize  Pool   Origin Data%  Meta%   
home   rhel_rheldemo Vwi-aotz-- 56.79g pool00        42.35                                  
pool00 rhel_rheldemo twi-aotz-- 78.79g               43.83  19.98                           
root   rhel_rheldemo Vwi-aotz--  3.00g pool00        35.95                                  
swap   rhel_rheldemo -wi-ao----  4.00g                                                      
tmp    rhel_rheldemo Vwi-aotz--  2.00g pool00        94.10                                  
usr    rhel_rheldemo Vwi-aotz-- 10.00g pool00        37.31                                  
var    rhel_rheldemo Vwi-aotz--  7.00g pool00        54.16      

[root@rheldemo ~]# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda2   VG rhel_rheldemo   lvm2 [98.54 GiB / 15.60 GiB free]
  Total: 1 [98.54 GiB] / in use: 1 [98.54 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

[root@rheldemo ~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               rhel_rheldemo
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  15
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                7
  Open LV               6
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               98.54 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25227
  Alloc PE / Size       21233 / 82.94 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       3994 / 15.60 GiB
  VG UUID               O7L00I-aILt-M4nS-FQz3-mQsR-fhjm-gvVKvb

[root@rheldemo ~]# fdisk -l
 Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
 Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 Disk label type: dos
 Disk identifier: 0x00094f6b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      526335      262144   83  Linux
/dev/sda2   *      526336   207192063   103332864   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/rhel_rheldemo-pool00_tmeta: 83 MB, 83886080 bytes, 163840 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/rhel_rheldemo-pool00_tdata: 84.6 GB, 84594917376 bytes, 165224448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
...
```

So, am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What exactly is wrong?  What do you hope/expect to see?

Comment: You're already using up almost 90G for your partitions... are you wondering where that 15 - 20 GB is?  You probably have to grow your root volume to use it.  As far as the VM is concerned, you have extra space you haven't used.